# How to change timezone of Oracle 9i Database

Tags: database, timezone, oracle9i

How to change Oracle 9i database timezone, 
I have a user schema with name 'HR_NU', its timezone is -07:00, I want to change it using alter query

```
alter database set time_zone='+05:00';
```

but getting errors

```
Error starting at line 10 in command:
alter database set time_zone='+05:00'
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-02231: missing or invalid option to ALTER DATABASE
02231. 00000 -  "missing or invalid option to ALTER DATABASE"
*Cause:    An option other than ADD, DROP, RENAME, ARCHIVELOG, NOARCHIVELOG,
           MOUNT, DISMOUNT, OPEN, or CLOSE is specified in the statement.
*Action:   Specify only legal options.
```

I google same issue, and came to know that if I have a  table containing a field of datatype timestamp with localtimezone then I will get above error, the solution suggested is change datatype of each column having datatype timestamp, but I have more than 300 tables, and about 200 columns of timestamp datatype.

Any help please.

Answer (score 0):

[SET TIME_ZONE [time_zone_region]]

can be also achieved like this " **set time_zone = 'America/New_York'** " 
have you tried that?